# Use a list of SKUs in a google sheet to pull their data from GOAT marketplace

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to pull the price data for each of the SKUs I have listed in a google sheet.

My initial try was the use a formula inside of the sheet.

> =importxml("SKU Search URL", "//p/span[@data-qa='grid-cell-price']/text()")

This does not work, since the content is dynamic.

What would be the easiest method of obtaining this data?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet, url and example of desired result

Comment: @player0 https://www.filemail.com/d/tnqgzgurswwslzn

Eveything is in that sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JavaScript controlled elements. you can easily check it by disabling JS for a given site and only what's left visible can be scraped. in your case, that's nothing, unfortunately:

[image]

Comment: I have become aware of this. I am looking for an alternative solution to this.

Comment: @NathanMorrison alternative solution includes alternative source